# Javascript object help (json and ajax)

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm currently using Ajax to pull data from my Json file... 
my situation is that in one div of my html i need to add a heading and paragraph..

I tried to make a property such as 
`"headingpara": "<h1> blah blah </h1> <p> blah blah blah </p>"` **With this i get an error.**

i also tried to do

```
"heading": "<h1> blah blah </h1>",
"para": "<p> blah blah blah </p>"
```

and then in my javascript call both properties with ["heading", "para"] **but it only shows the paragraph and not the heading..**

how can i put both the h1 and p tags side one div using this?

Comment: "With this i get an error" -> which one? moreover, please share your code in a fiddle or something, we can't help you if we can't see what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property innerHTML to concat your HTML strings building the content of the target div.

```js
var ajaxresponse = {
"heading": "<h1> blah blah </h1>",
"para": "<p> blah blah blah </p>"
};

document.querySelector('#target_div').innerHTML = ajaxresponse.heading+ajaxresponse.para;
```

```html
<div id="target_div"></div>
```

Comment: This didn't fix my problem although it gave me an idea to put .heading and .para into seperate variables and then concat them together. Thank you for this help :)